# Compute the Lebesgue integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x}{e^x -1}dx$.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Compute the Lebesgue integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x}{e^x -1}dx$.

I think I need to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem or the Beppo Levi Theorem to show this, but I don't really know what I should do with the function. How can I compute this integral? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Just because this question came after learning these. But I'm completely lost on how to evaluate this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty xe^{-nx}$$

Comment: Can you tell me how to get this equality?

Comment: @takecare $e^{-nx}=(e^{-x})^n$. This is a geometric series.